# Imagenes en la cabecera de Itext 5.0

Tags: java, itext

Estoy trabajando con **Itext 5.0** para JAVA(uso Idea ), pero no encuentro información de cómo añadir imágenes en la cabecera ( como si fuera un membrete ). Lo único que puedo hacer es declarar la posición absoluta de la imagen con `Imagen.setAbsolutePosition()` indicándole la posición más alta para las `x`, `y` 0 para el eje y, pero veo que aún deja espacio entre el top de las páginas y la imagen (lo cual, siendo una cabecera no tiene mucho sentido ). Tengo los márgenes superior e inferior declarados a 0 con `documento.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);`.

Mi consulta es cómo añadir la imagen en el sitio correcto.

Muy agradecido de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Como veres a continuación defino los márgenes del documento
y luego agrego la imagen.

Este es un ejemplo:

```
Document documento = new Document(PageSize.A4,10,10,10,10);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(archivo));
                documento.open();
imagen = Image.getInstance("dirección de la ubicación de tu imagen");
imagen.scalePercent(75f);//esto es opcional para definir el tamaño de la imagen.
imagen.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
documento.add(imagen);
```

El resultado sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, parece que funciona bien